If $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=1$, then $f_n(x)=f(nx)$ is not uniformly convergent
I have the following problem:

Suppose $f:(0,\infty)\to\mathbb R$ is such that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=1$. Prove that if $f$ is not constant, then the sequence of functions $\{f_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ defined on $(0,\infty)$ by $f_n(x)=f(nx)$ is not uniformly convergent.

I’ve tried to find to points $x_1,x_2\in(0,\infty)$ that are far
and tried to find $y$ so $\lvert f(y)-1\rvert>\varepsilon$
but struggled doing so. My best attempt was setting
$y = \sup \left\{ |f_n(x) - 1| : x \in (0, \infty) \right\}$, but this did not seem right.
Thanks for helping.

Do you mind reorganize your question in a clearer way ? It is hard to understand what the question is.

Hint: If $|f(t) - 1| > \epsilon$, where do you know $|f_n(x) - 1| > \epsilon$?

Can you reconstruct ur question carefully?

If $f$ is non-constant, then $f(\xi)\neq1$ for some $\xi\in(0,\infty)$. As $f_n(x)\to1$ as $n\to\infty$ for all $x\in(0,\infty)$, if it converged uniformly then the limit function would be the constant function $1$. But observe now that
$$\sup_{x\in(0,\infty)}\lvert f_n(x)-1\rvert\geq\left\lvert f_n\left(\frac{\xi}{n}\right)-1\right\rvert=\left\lvert f(\xi)-1\right\rvert$$
for all $n$, so in particular if it did converge uniformly we would have that
$$0=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{x\in(0,\infty)}\lvert f_n(x)-1\rvert\geq\lvert f(\xi)-1\rvert>0,$$
which is a contradiction.

I really like this solution appreciate the help fr!
